# SHA1 collision for first 32 bits for two different messages

Tags: sha-1

Is it possible to create a program to find the collision of 2 different messages with the same first 32 bits using sha1 hashing? I tried using a while loop, but it ran endlessly as though no match were found. I am doing this in Java. These 2 messages must contain "abc123".

My while logic is adding a number to the end of the string, but it fails.

Below is my sha1 hashing (let's just call it) pseudo-code:

```
public static String sha1Hashing (String message) {
    String sha1 = "";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        byte[] result = mDigest.digest(message.getBytes());

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((result[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return first 32 char
    sha1 = sb.toString().substring(0,32);
    return sha1;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that the above hashing function actually returns the first 32 bits of the SHA-1 hash; it looks like it returns more; that'd explain a failure to find a partial collision.  This question might be better suited for stackexchange, as it's a question about programming, and not cryptography.

Comment: That code is just completely wrong. You're not altering the message at all, and I don't see you comparing 32 bits either. First *decompose your problem* and generate multiple methods for each part. Test these separately. Then combine them to to create the code. For instance, the comparison of the 4 bytes can be separated out. So can the generation of the messages and  - of course - the creation of the hash.

Answer (score 4):

To find a collision it would be best to perform a birthday attack (as I already commented below the question).

You could use `abc123` as prefix and then append a counter (using any encoding), creating the message to hash. Then you'd calculate a hash over the message and take the first 4 bytes. You'd create a *map* using the 4 byte hash as key (e.g. encoded as hexadecimals) and the message.

Now you simply add these key / value pairs until you find a duplicate key. In that case you print out the current message and the message in the map, and - of course - the hash collision that you found.

Because of the birthday problem you'd expect to find a match in less than a second and minimal memory use.

---

Proof:

```
Found match: abc123_owlstead_1255 and abc123_owlstead_59131 -> 992156E0
That took approximately 430 milli seconds
```

Note that if you post this as an answer, the word "owlstead" should raise some questions and google will quickly find this answer. So I would not copy paste this answer if I were you.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to find a match for the entire hash and not just the first 4 bytes?

Comment: Not for a secure, collision resistant hash, but in this case [SHA-1 is not a secure hash](https://shattered.it). I'm not sure if you would call that "efficient" though.

Comment: Re last line: I still catch myself correcting some of my old comments due to that owl… ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to find 2 strings with the same first 32 bits sha1. For example, the first 32 bits of the sha1 of the hex strings 616263313233bffa0000 and 616263313233e6280100 are both e5c993e0. You can use a birthday attack. `substring(0,32)` gives you the first 32 bytes. You want the first 32 bits or the first 8 bytes. You should use `substring(0,8)`.